# How to get top 5 most ram intensive applications from Bash?

Tags: bash, shell-script, ram

So I look at avaliable to me servers load

[image]

and see that some other user has created some really ram intensive app that kills my server hosting abileties. I wonder what is bash command to get top 5 most ram using applications n my server. How would such command look like?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `ps`:

```
ps axo pid,args,pmem,rss,vsz --sort -pmem,-rss,-vsz | head -n 5
```

Answer (score 4):

Run `top`.  Press `O` to change the sort order, and `Q` for RESident memory.